# How to include a check in code needed to pass a particular test case?

Tags: arrays

Following is the Problem:
Given an array arr of integers, check if there exists two integers N and M such that N is the double of M ( i.e. N = 2 * M).

More formally check if there exists two indices i and j such that :

`i != j`
`0 <= i, j < arr.length`
`arr[i] == 2 * arr[j]`

Example 1:

Input: arr = [10,2,5,3]
Output: true
Explanation: N = 10 is the double of M = 5,that is, 10 = 2 * 5.
Example 2:

Input: arr = [7,1,14,11]
Output: true
Explanation: N = 14 is the double of M = 7,that is, 14 = 2 * 7.
Example 3:

Input: arr = [3,1,7,11]
Output: false
Explanation: In this case does not exist N and M, such that N = 2 * M.

Constraints:

2 <= arr.length <= 500
-10^3 <= arr[i] <= 10^3

My Solution

```
    class Solution {
        public boolean checkIfExist(int[] arr) {
            int [] arr2 = new int[arr.length];

            boolean answer= false;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr2[i]=2*arr[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = arr.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {

                    if((arr[i]) == arr2[j]){ 
                        answer=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            return answer;
        }
    }
```

When the input array is [-2,0,10,-19,4,6,-8] the test case fails, because of the 0 in the 2nd index is doubled but when there is a 0 in any place it should be ignored.

Comment: What part of your code is trying to handle the 0?

Comment: That is what I am trying to ask as a question ,how can I do that?

Comment: What part of your code is *identifying* the 0's that need to be handled?

Comment: when i compare using if((arr[i]) == arr2[j]){ 
                        answer=true;
                        break;
                    }    

Here I can do something when arr[I] ==0.

Answer (score 0):

adding arr[i] != 0 to your if statement will skip over any 0
Here is an example

```
var arr = [10, 4, 8, 5, 16, 0]

for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(var j=0; j < arr.length; j++){
    if(arr[i] != 0 && arr[i] * 2 == arr[j])
        console.log(arr[i], arr[j])
  }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: what if the input array is [0,0] ?

Comment: [0,0] doesn't get passed the test. Because anytime arr[i] is a 0 it is ignored

Answer (score 0):

The corrected Solution is

```
class Solution {
        public boolean checkIfExist(int[] arr) {
            int [] arr2 = new int[arr.length];

            boolean answer= false;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                arr2[i]=2*arr[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = arr.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {

                    if(i == j){
                         continue;
                    }  if(arr[i] == arr2[j]){
                        answer=true;
                        break;
                        }  
                }
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }
```